# Большое количество ImageView в одном активити. Как правильно загрузить в них картинки, чтобы избежать OutOfMemory?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!
В моем активити расположены  12 ImageView, и я в них загрузил картинки. Но, увы, дабы избежать OutOfMemory, мне пришлось сильно урезать размер картинок.

Про данный ресурс - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html знаю, но, говорят, что когда нужно загрузить большое количество картинок, нужно использовать этот метод (который описан по ссылке) в AsyncTask. Но я не представляю, как это сделать.

Прошу объясните или, если вам не трудно, напишите пример того, как это реализовать.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: У вас картики все на одном экране или это список?

Comment: Не в списке, а в одном активити. Плиткой расположены, если быть точнее.

Answer (score 1):

AsynkTask поможет тебе лишь загрузить картинки в другом потоке. Это целесообразно, т.к. загрузка большого числа картинок - это тяжелый код, который, выполняясь в главном потоке, приведет к ANR. От OutOfMemory же AsynkTask тебя не спасет.

Тебе нужно воспользоваться библиотекой Glide - она сжимает картинки до нужного размера, сводя к минимуму занимаемую память и, конечно, сама сделает это в другом потоке. Это тоже, правда, не спасет тебя от OutOfMemory, но вероятность его возникновеня будет на порядок ниже

Comment: У AsyncTask есть три метода: doInBackground, onPreExecute и onPostExecute. Каким именно из них нужно пользоваться в данной ситуации?

Comment: Никаким, все они бесполезны